# Detecting Changes in an ASP.NET Web Site

Tags: asp.net

The ASP.NET framework does a very good job of detecting when a file has changed and recompiling that file etc.  I would like to be able to hook into that update process.  Is this at all possible?

I might want to do this as part of an initiative to try and version web sites developed as *Web Site* projects, versus *Web Applications*, where the version is easily found in statically deployed assemblies.  If I my be misdirecting my energies as there are already better way if versioning web *sites*, I'd still appreciate some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can hook into that logic at all - perhaps you could add your code to [`Application_OnStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2(VS.71).aspx) as this method will fire when ASP.NET recycles the AppPool and restarts the website.

Comment: I was about to answer that, but your link goes to BizTalk.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Web Deployment projects](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459)?

[Scott Gu has a blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/06/429723.aspx).

Comment: Interesting, but it pertains to pre-built sites, where I prefer the 'compile on demand' model, i.e. just deploy source and let the pipeline build.  My problem is that the deployer can replace any source file without recording it.

Comment: I think you're problem is then in the human part of the workflow and who has access to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ASP.NET SignalR](http://signalr.net/) to do it, It's real-time web for .NET

Answer (score 0):

This might put you on the right path (might -- I haven't tried this).

http://www.codersource.net/csharp_iis_metabase.html (dead link)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried developing a separate module for ASP.NET that keeps track of last change?